# Proof of Limit if and only if limit of absolute value is the same

Tags: analysis

The question from my textbook is as follows:

> Prove any sequence $\{a_n\}$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$.

My attempt:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n\in N$ such that $|an -0| = |a_n| = ||a_n|-0| < \epsilon$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n\in N$ such that $||a_n| - 0| = a_n = |a_n - 0| < \epsilon$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

I thought that my proof is a bit sketchy. Is my proof a valid proof? If not, how would I go about solving this?

Comment: I'd say you did fine on the first part. For the second part, use the fact that $-|a_n| \le a_n \le |a_n|$.

Comment: I think this proof is correct. You should specify that the same $n$ works both the sequences.

Comment: You reasoning is correct but your definition of limits is mangled.  It isn't there exist an n so that ... blah.... that is just one value.  The def is there exist and M so that for all n > M then .... blah.  Do you see the difference and why it is important?  But your reasoning $|a_n| = |a_n - 0| = ||a_n|-0|$ is just fine and that is indeed all you need to demonstrate to prove this.  (Just use the *correct* definition of limits though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only problem is that you don't have the correct definition of limit.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = c$ means that for any $\epsilon$ there exists and $M \in \mathbb R$ so that $n > M; n \in \mathbb N$ will imply $|a_n - c| < \epsilon$.

You stated something entirely different.

Then as $|a_n - 0| = |a_n| = ||a_n| - 0|$ we have $|an - 0| < \epsilon \iff ||a_n| - 0|<\epsilon$ and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n =0 \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n| =0$.

The part of your proof that felt sketchy was just fine.  But the part that felt just fine (the definition of limit) was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look fine to me.

For example for the first part, you argued that
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n\in\mathbb{N} : ||a_n|-0|<\epsilon\tag{1}
$$
and concluded that
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0\tag{2}
$$
While $(1)$ is true, it is not equivalent to $(2)$. The meaning of $(2)$ is
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : n>N \implies ||a_n|-0|<\epsilon\tag{3}
$$
Of course the same argument you gave will lead you to $(3)$.

> **Note:** Define
>   $$
> a_n := \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n} & n \text{ even}\\1 & n \text{ odd}\end{cases}
> $$
>   Then the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies $(1)$ but not $(2)$.

As for the second implication you tried to prove, you ran into the same problem and also the equality $||a_n| - 0| = a_n$ isn't true if $a_n<0$ (which can happen).

---

All you need in order to prove the result is to note (as you did) that
$$
|a_n-0| = ||a_n|-0|
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0\\
\Updownarrow \\
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : n>N \implies |a_n-0|<\epsilon \\
\Updownarrow \\
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : n>N \implies ||a_n|-0|<\epsilon \\
\Updownarrow \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct. You're emphasizing that *there exists (at least) one $n$* that fits. But what you should say is *those n large enough* will fit.

> $\epsilon$-$\delta$$(\epsilon$-$K)$ method is like a machine:
>   *For any given $\epsilon$, you put the $\epsilon$ into it, and get a corresponding $\delta$$(K)$*.

In your proof, you don't take the advantage of the *correspnding $K^\dagger$* from the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\bullet)$.

$^\dagger K\in \Bbb{Z}^+$.

Assume LHS is true: $$\forall \epsilon\gt 0, \exists K \in \Bbb{N}, \forall n\in \Bbb{N}: n\ge K\implies |a_n - 0|\lt\epsilon,$$

which implies the RHS is true, by the reasoning you given, if you choose **the just corresponding K** to limit your $n$. The reverse is similar.

Comment: No need for triangle inequality, it's a bit redudant

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Ok I've fixed it, thanks for the good catch.